# Copulas with regime-switching random variables

Tags: correlation, bootstrap, copula

I have a large number of correlated data that I am attempting to simulate. I have already bootstrapped the parametric distributions of each time series, computed the correlation matrix for the series, and applied the inverse transform to the Gaussian copula. My quandary, however, is that the bootstraps are usually regime-switching, taking on the value of their fitted distribution, g(x), with probability p and taking a value of zero with probability (1-p). The question is: How can I reflect the correlation among the variables in the regime-switching setting? I was considering generating another set of Gaussian copulas, such that if the CDF of the multivariate Gaussian is F(x, y) < p, then use g(x) with the value from the first copula; otherwise set the value to zero.

Is this a valid approach? Any suggestions? Your help is immensely appreciated!